# Some ploblem in convert QByteArray to QDataStream and save.Please help me

Tags: qt

following is my code:

```
QFile f("tql.dll"); //a file to be copied
f.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
QByteArray qba = f.readAll();
f.close();
QString hexstr = qba.toHex();
qba = QByteArray::fromHex(hexstr.toLatin1()); //i try this and it dose not change the original data
QFile f2("tql3.dll");
f2.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
QDataStream out(&f2);
out << qba;
f2.close();
qDebug() << "done" << "\n"; //when i md5sum the tql3.dll.it is not the same as tql.dll
```

I used vim to see the hex of tql.dll and tql3.dll to find what the difference is.Then i found that there is "00 00 EC 00" extra at the top in tql3.dll.why?

PS:i know it is ok to save QByteArray to QFile direct.but i just want to try QDataStream.

Answer (score 2):

`QDatastream` is meant to portably stream Qt types, not plain binary data.

When you output to QDataStream, for each variable there is a header with internal data (I assume type + length).

see http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QDataStream.html#details:

> Each item written to the stream is written in a predefined binary
>   format that varies depending on the item's type

.

Comment: so how to save QByteArray using stream?

Comment: As you said, just save to QFile directly. The notion of "streaming" is, by definition, for structured data, not for pure binary ones. Why do you want to use streams?

Answer (score 0):

[The data stream format page](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/datastreamformat.html) states how `QByteArray`s are stored:

> If the byte array is null: 0xFFFFFFFF (quint32)
>   Otherwise: the array size (quint32) followed by the array bytes, i.e. size bytes

Those four bytes (32 bit) you posted are thus the length of the byte array.

`QDataStream` is supposed to be used for serialization and my thus be unable to create 1:1 file copies.

Comment: so how to save QByteArray using stream?

Answer (score 0):

.Actually... there is a way to do this.  But first you must realize there are potential problems with your code:

1. if you are trying to convert to binary data using a hex string, this
   will not work at all!   Remember that a string does not actually
   represent binary data.  For example: 16 bit binary 'FF' is written
   in binary (using hex notation) as FF.  But the STRING FF is written
   (using same 16 bit binary format) as 46 46
2. using QString::toLatin1() will **NOT** output the text in unicode
   form.  I understand that may not be your goal here but for general
   knowledge's sake, characters will only be converted to Latin1 format
   if their is an ASCII equivalent for the character.  If you want full
   unicode support you should use QString::toUtf8().

**Now for the solution.**  If you want to convert a QByteArray to a QDataStream you can use the QDataStream::writeBytes(const char *s, uint length) function in combination with QByteArray::data() and QByteArray::size().

In your code you would want to replace your `out << qba` line with the following:

```
out.writeBytes(qba.data(), qba.size());
```

**A safer way to do it would be to use the following code:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < qba.size(); ++i)
{
    out << (quint8)qba.at(i);
}
```